# Windows Power Options - Turn off the display - HDMI not saving energy

Tags: windows, display, hdmi, power, energy-saving

I recently purchased a BenQ GL2760H Monitor which has both HDMI/VGA/DVI inputs.  I have a Dell Desktop with Window 7 which has a built-in Intel graphics card with just HDMI and VGA outputs.  I also have a "Kill A Watt" device which tells me how many watts an electronic device is outputting.  When I hook the monitor up to the computer using HDMI it uses 14 watts (I am using an economy mode on the monitor), but when Windows power saving options turn off the monitor, even though the screen turns black I can still see a faint glow, so I know that the LED lights are still on.  And the monitor is now using 15 watts while displaying nothing.

If I hook the monitor up to the computer using a VGA cable then it uses 14 watts, and when power saving options turn off the monitor it then uses 0 watts. This is what is supposed to happen.  I would like to use the HDMI cable, but I don't want it to be using any energy while in power saving mode.
Is this a regular problem with HDMI? Or could it be a problem with the monitor or windows or the Intel chipset?

Comment: If you unhook the monitor from HDMI when computer is on, does usage drops to 0 watt? And then when you rehook the HDMI, does the monitor wake up from sleep?

Comment: If I unhook the HDMI then the monitor displays "No Cable Connected" and the energy goes up to 29 watts.  When I plug the HDMI cable back in then the monitor goes black and down to 0 watts.  When I move the mouse it wakes up and displays windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered my own question.  I updated the Intel HD Graphics 4600 driver for windows and now when Windows power saving options turns off the monitor while connected to HDMI, the energy goes down to 0 watts and fluctuates between 1 and 0 watts.  Not as good as the 0 watts all the time with VGA but much better than it was doing on HDMI before I updated the driver.